# Storm Trident HDFS Bolt is throwing error

Tags: hadoop, jms, hdfs, apache-storm, trident

**Storm Trident topology is throwing errors like below when i try to send JMS Text Message from Trident JMS spout to the Trident hdfs bolt while trying to write the messages in HDFS.**

Did any one came across this kind of error and what do you think this is if you faced it?

```
25518 [Thread-86-b-0] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:107) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:78) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:77) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5870$fn__5882$fn__5929.invoke(executor.clj:745) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__442.invoke(util.clj:436) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.trident.format.DelimitedRecordFormat.format(DelimitedRecordFormat.java:73) ~[StormTridentXml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.trident.HdfsState$HdfsFileOptions.execute(HdfsState.java:193) ~[StormTridentXml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.trident.HdfsState.updateState(HdfsState.java:328) ~[StormTridentXml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.trident.HdfsUpdater.updateState(HdfsUpdater.java:29) ~[StormTridentXml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.trident.HdfsUpdater.updateState(HdfsUpdater.java:26) ~[StormTridentXml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at storm.trident.planner.processor.PartitionPersistProcessor.finishBatch(PartitionPersistProcessor.java:98) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at storm.trident.planner.SubtopologyBolt.finishBatch(SubtopologyBolt.java:152) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.finishBatch(TridentBoltExecutor.java:252) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.checkFinish(TridentBoltExecutor.java:285) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.execute(TridentBoltExecutor.java:359) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5870$tuple_action_fn__5872.invoke(executor.clj:630) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5793.invoke(executor.clj:398) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__2793.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:104) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Our Storm Version is 0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563

and Storm-Hdfs is 0.9.4

Comment: Have you looked at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.storm/storm-hdfs/0.9.4/org/apache/storm/hdfs/trident/format/DelimitedRecordFormat.java? It looks as though you haven't specified any fields. Also please add some code, it's going to be almost impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: I added two fields into the storm tuple coming from JmsSpout which implements ITridentSpout<JmsBatch> . now error is like this Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at storm.trident.tuple.TridentTupleView.getValueByPointer(TridentTupleView.java:326) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
        at storm.trident.tuple.TridentTupleView.getValueByField(TridentTupleView.java:277) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563.jar:0.9.1.2.1.3.0-563]
        at com.tda.trident.bolt.DelimitedRecordFormat.format(DelimitedRecordFormat.java:79) ~[StormTridentXml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]

Comment: I am trying to Collect XML Messages from JMS QUEUE and trying to put them in HDFS. Currently i am using JMS Spout and HDFS State in Storm Trident. What is the difference between JMS Spout and JMS State. Which is better to use in my case?